# Xamarin C# - Calling Async Methods from other classes

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile

For each page in the project, I have Async Methods that push onto the Navigation like the following:

```
async void LoadOtherPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
}
```

Multiple pages have the same function defined due to the purpose of the application. However, I don't want to have to keep redefining the functions for each individual page. I want to just define all my async functions in one static class that I can just call to switch pages. My attempted solution is the following:

```
static class PageCaller
{
   static async public void LoadOtherPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Navigation.PushAsync is not defined when I make the class and function static. Is there a simple way of defining all my async Page Calling functions just once and then calling them when I need to push onto the Navigation Stack?

Comment: Navigation is a property of Page, so it only exists on Pages.  2 simple approaches: 1) create your own base page class that defines the function, and have your other pages inherit from it, or 2) use Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation in your static class

Comment: I changed it to
```
static class PageCaller
{
   static async public void LoadOtherPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
      await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
   }
}
```
and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to

```
static class PageCaller
{
   static async public void LoadOtherPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
      await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
   }
}
```

and it works. Thank you!